# Moving empty space behind Ubuntu partition to extend Windows partition

Tags: partition, uefi

I recently purchased a new SSD for my laptop as I was running out of drive space. There is only space for one SSD in my laptop so I had to clone the entire existing drive to the new SSD and then swap them. This was successful with no problems. The only issue was that the extra space was at the end of the drive, when ideally I wanted to extend my windows partition as that is what I use most often, I only use Ubuntu for some specific development tasks and don't need much space. I made do for a while by just using the extra space as an extra storage drive, but I am starting to run out of space on the Windows drive again, and would really like to consolidate everything to the Windows drive.

Here is the current UEFI drive structure and what I want to achieve:
[image: drive structure]

From my perspective there are a couple of ways to potentially achieve this:

1. Using GParted Live CD to move the partitions
2. Using an external drive to clone the Ubuntu and WINRETOOLS partitions to, then deleting them from my drive, extending the Windows partition, deleting the Storage partition, then cloning the Ubuntu and WINRETOOLS partitions back to my drive.
3. Deleting Ubuntu entirely, extending Windows partition, then reinstalling Ubuntu

Is option 1 feasible?
Option 2 should work but has a lot of ways things could go wrong.
Option 3 would work and is safe, but is a real pain because installing Ubuntu 16.04 (which I need) on my laptop was not fun.
Are there any other ways? How would you recommend going about this?

Cheers

Comment: If you have good backups, reinstalling Ubuntu should not be a major issue. You need /home & list of installed applications. Perhaps some files in /etc if you manually edited system files. And if server or server type applications those folders in / (root). You can install in 10 minutes to SSD. If faster Internet downloading apps is also quick. Within an hour you can usually have a fully restored system. Another alternative is just to use space as a data partition. Often best not to mount Windows c: drive in Linux, but you can mount a separate NTFS data partition, if Windows fast start off.

Comment: can you drop the "E" drive - that would make the reshuffle easier.